# W3CDTF specification regular expression for validating dates

Tags: php, regex, validation, date

I have this to check if a date is valid based on the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime):

```
/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2})(:(\d{2}))?(?:([-+])(\d{2}):?(\d{2})|(Z))?/
```

The following formats are accepted:

```
   Year:
      YYYY (eg 1997)
   Year and month:
      YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
   Complete date:
      YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
   Complete date plus hours and minutes:
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)
   Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
   Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a
second
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
```

`2005-04-05` never matches and I can't for the life of me figure it out. According to the pattern, it should match.

Comment: Right now your Matching requires the T and Time info, it is not optional

Answer (score 2):

Think about building this up with an OR type approach and then look to simplify with a look behind if you want:

```
(\d{4})|(\d{4}-\d{2})|(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}(:\d{2}){1,2}[-+]\d{2}:\d{2})
```

Also, this is not checking for valid numbers for dates which can be done pretty easily if you modularize it take it step by step. An example for a date could look like:

```
\d{4}-(([0]{0,1}[\d])|(1[0-2]))-(([0-2]{0,1}[\d])|(3[01]))
```

Note this assumes only 4 digit years and that any 4 digit year is OK. It also allow for both 01 and 1 as single digit month and day numbers. Also some extra bracketing for clarity.